# What is the grammar of the conditional "If students are having difficulties..., early detection can help"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conditionals

I read an essay, and one of the sentences is like this.

> ***If*** students ***are having*** difficulties with basic skills like reading, writing and mathematics, early detection ***can help*** educators to remediate their skills.

I believe the grammar falls into the category of conditionals, most probably first conditional, but the rule for first conditional is like this:

- If + present simple, will + infinitive

Where this sentence is like this (pls correct me if I'm wrong):

- If + present continuous + model verb

Can you point out to me what is the correct grammar for this sentence, as I'm unable to find the answer so far?

Comment: It is the zero conditional form.

Comment: How many conditional forms are there, and who decides? Is there a Conditional Academy with regular meetings?

Comment: @John Lawler I think tchrist was up to ~250 at the last count.

Comment: Observation on this site suggests that it's the Secret Masters of TEFL who have decided.

Answer (score 0):

This is the First Conditional sentence.

### First Conditional

If + Present Simple/**Present Continuous**, will(**can**/could/may) + **bare infinitive**/imperative

We use 1-st Conditional to:

1. Talk about real conditions in the present or future and their results in the present/future.
2. To give conditional instructions.

> *If students **are having** difficulties with basic skills, early detection **can help** educators to remediate their skills.*

---

However, this sentence can be rewritten into the Zero Conditional form:

> *If students **have** difficulties with basic skills, early detection **helps** educators to remediate their skills.*

The last example implies that this is a well known fact and it is always true.